How do i restart my account after replay in progress has me stuck
Every time I try to use my account.It says transaction is not possible because a replay is in progress.

"Account"
You say "account", which makes the rest of your question unclear to me because Bitcoin was designed to work with no accounts. The normal type of wallet is a software program you download onto a phone or PC and run yourself without any link to a business. Some businesses offer Bitcoin accounts of various sorts but these work very differently from normal Bitcoin wallets. If you have opened an account with one of the many many online Bitcoin businesses, the following information will not apply.
"Bitcoin Wallet" app for Android, developed by "Bitcoin Wallet Developers" (The Schildbach wallet)
There is an old discussion on Bitcointalk about a similar problem in the Bitcoin Wallet for Android, by "Bitcoin Wallet Developers"
The exact message shown was

Currently Payments are not possible because a replay is in progress

That is different to your

transaction is not possible because a replay is in progress.

But perhaps you didn't remember it exactly
The person who asked about this on Bitcointalk seems to have eventually solved the problem by allowing the app to complete synchronising with the network - by just waiting patiently.
The discussion there suggests an alternative approach of recovering by transferring keys to a desktop wallet but I think this is too complex for anyone new to Bitcoin and involves the use of rather technical Linux commands.

Also, in a comment at The App's page in Google-Play store it says


Why it say "replay in progress"?? What does that even mean? I cant send any bitcoins because of it. Edit: after update i got my transaction. But now i tried to send coins and its been stuck for 5 days. No response from developers by email. Did a report about transaction with data, still no response after 3 days.

Bitcoin Wallet developers 26 juni 2024
This issue is fixed in version 10.15, which you can update to via > Google Play.

So you might try updating to the latest version if you are using an older version than 10.15.
